# cakephp 3 bootstrap-ui change prev/next text

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-bootstrap-ui

I have FriendsofCake Bootstrap-ui plugin. I see in the source that it accepts text for the pagination prev and next labels.

I am not sure how to exactly set the config option though.

PaginatorHelper.php

```
    if (isset($options['next'])) {
        if ($options['next'] === true) {
            $options['next'] = $this->config('labels.next');
        }
        $options['after'] = $this->next($options['next'], ['escape' => false]) . $options['after'];
    }
```

I was trying this below in the bootstrap.php but no effect

```
Configure::write('friendsofcake.PaginatorHelper.labels.prev', 'previous');
```

But I see they are also set in the `__construct`

**Answer**

With the help from drmonkeyninja here is the exact code needed to configure the labels in the AppView.php

```
$this->loadHelper(
    'Paginator',
    [
        'className' => 'BootstrapUI.Paginator',
        'labels' => [
            'prev' => 'previous',
            'next' => 'next',
        ]
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be badly documented, but to configure any of the settings for a helper you need to pass them as an array when you load it. So for example, if you are loading the Paginator helper inside your AppView you would pass `prev`like this:-

```
$this->loadHelper(
    'Paginator', 
    [
        'className' => 'BootstrapUI.Paginator', 
        'prev' => 'previous'
    ]
);
```

Comment: thanks for the help :-) I have updated my answer to show the exact code needed for the labels.